# Linq custom OrderBy using constants

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to sort a list of items that have an ID, but I would like to implement a custom sort order based on constants. The following works, but I am not a big fan of the lambda expression. Is there a better way to do this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myList = new List<MyItem> 
        {
          new MyItem {SomeId = 1}, 
          new MyItem {SomeId = 2}, 
          new MyItem {SomeId = 3}, 
          new MyItem {SomeId = 4}, 
          new MyItem {SomeId = 5}
        };

        var orderedList = myList
          .OrderBy(list => list.SomeId == SomeIdConstants.FIRST 
            ? 1 
            : list.SomeId == SomeIdConstants.SECOND 
              ? 2 
              : list.SomeId == SomeIdConstants.THIRD 
                ? 3 
                : list.SomeId == SomeIdConstants.FOURTH 
                  ? 4 : 5);

        foreach (var listItem in orderedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.SomeId);
        }
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
}

public class SomeIdConstants
{
    public const int FIRST = 2;
    public const int SECOND = 1;
    public const int THIRD = 4;
    public const int FOURTH = 5;
    public const int FIFTH = 3;
}
```

Comment: `public enum SomeIdConstants : int` would probably be better than a class, and are you sure about `FIRST = 2`?

Comment: @theB I believe the OP means that the value of 2 should come first.

Comment: You could use the `OrderBy` that take an `IComparer` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @juharr - I just want to confirm that those constants are correct. I'm following the value -> order mapping.

Comment: @theB I could use an enum as well, but juharr is correct, I just want the order of 2,1,4,5,3 in this example.

Comment: @juharr I did look at IComparer, but I wasn't sure how I would use it. From what I was looking at, I would want something like : IComparer<int>, but my implementation of the Compare method would take in two int parameters and I wasn't sure how that would work when I only want to compare the single value to a constant.

Comment: Yep, the OP is answered, just from a design perspective looking at your comment of selected answer, don't you actually need a method like `GetOrdinalFromId` OR it Might be a `dictionary` of key value pairs? where key is your id, value is the correct ordinal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put them into an ordered collection:

```
int[] orderConstants = { SomeIdConstants.FIRST, SomeIdConstants.SECOND, SomeIdConstants.THIRD, SomeIdConstants.FOURTH, SomeIdConstants.FIFTH };
```

then you can use `Array.IndexOf` (if you've put them into a list use `List.IndexOf`):

```
var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(orderConstants, i.SomeId));
```

Comment: I ended up using a combination of sloth's answer with a list and your answer, but selected yours because it does use the constants that was in my initial question. I know the constants probably don't make a lot of sense in this example, but the actual constants I am using are a class that maps up to a type table so I like to be able to change that in one place. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

You could use a `List` instead, like

```
var lookup = new List<int> {2, 1, 4, 5, 3};
var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(list => lookup.IndexOf(list.SomeId));
```

This puts elements with a SomeId that's not in `lookup` at the front (this may or may not be an issue for you. If it is, it's trivial to handle this).

Comment: It's not clear how the constants come into play. What if OP wants to reorder all queries by changing the constant values? He also has to remember that there might be collections which don't refer to the constants but mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Custom Comparer

**EDIT:** using enum for order

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<MyItem>
        { 
            new MyItem { SomeId = 1 },
            new MyItem { SomeId = 2 },
            new MyItem { SomeId = 3 },
            new MyItem { SomeId = 4 },
            new MyItem { SomeId = 5 }
        };

        var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(d => d, new MyItemComparer());
        foreach (var listItem in orderedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.SomeId);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemComparer : IComparer<MyItem>
{
    public int Compare(MyItem i1, MyItem i2)
    {
        int pos1 = pos(i1);
        int pos2 = pos(i2);

        if (pos1 > pos2) { return 1; }
        if (pos1 < pos2) { return -1; }
        return 0;
    }

    // Return the required position for a value of SomeId
    private int pos(MyItem it)
    {
        switch (it.SomeId)
        {
            case (int)SomeIdConstants.FIRST: return 1;
            case (int)SomeIdConstants.SECOND: return 2;
            case (int)SomeIdConstants.THIRD: return 3;
            case (int)SomeIdConstants.FOURTH: return 4;
            case (int)SomeIdConstants.FIFTH: return 5;
            default: return 999;
        }
    }
}

public enum SomeIdConstants : int
{
    FIRST = 2,
    SECOND = 1,
    THIRD = 4,
    FOURTH = 5,
    FIFTH = 3
}
```